# Recommend a proxy server for Dropbox

Tags: proxy, firewall, dropbox

I live in China and used Dropbox extensively up until it was blocked this last week.  Is it possible to use a proxy server with Dropbox?  Which ones should I try?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/).  It's meant for privacy but it should allow you to access the dropbox servers without being blocked.  It might take a bit of setup but you can use it with a wide range of software, not just Dropbox:

> Tor protects you by bouncing your
>   communications around a distributed
>   network of relays run by volunteers
>   all around the world: it prevents
>   somebody watching your Internet
>   connection from learning what sites
>   you visit, and it prevents the sites
>   you visit from learning your physical
>   location. Tor works with many of your
>   existing applications, including web
>   browsers, instant messaging clients,
>   remote login, and other applications
>   based on the TCP protocol.

Comment: This is a good advice unless big amounts of data are passed to/from Dropbox, since pushing lots of data over Tor is generally considered rude.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding the alternative IP in your hosts file:

> 174.36.30.71 www.dropbox.com